# How to run vuejs backend postgres api?

Tags: postgresql, api, vue.js

We have a server and desktop computers on the same network. I am building a business application and have not found a way to directly work with Postgresql from vuejs. I have found that I can go through an API to work with Postgresql. I have built the API and it is in its own folder within the vuejs app and I run nodemon to start. I can make a production vuejs app but ...

How do I use the API in production?

How do I have the API autostart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a node module called node-windows. And this video about node-windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1smy9yyme1Y
I moved my backend API folder to my server and followed the video to add the node module and script to my server.

The module will autostart the service.